# Defining my own custom maven repository in Android gradle build script

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know Maven repositories can be added normally using something similar to the following snippet.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

However, what I would like to achieve is actually creating my own Maven repository entry.  So adding to the example above, this might look something like the following.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        myNewRepo()
    }
}
```

Note that "myNewRepo" is the new repository and was added to the bottom.  If I simply add the string as show above, I get the following error from gradle.

> Could not find method myRepo() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

My reason for doing this is that I have a list of several of my own Maven repositories and it gets burdensome to have to each of these entries for all of my apps.  For example, my current implementation looks like this.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url: "some url"
            name: "some name"
        }
        maven {
            url: "some url"
            name: "some name"
        }
        maven {
            url: "some url"
            name: "some name"
        }
        maven {
            url: "some url"
            name: "some name"
        }
        maven {
            url: "some url"
            name: "some name"
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like creating my own repository entry can make this a lot cleaner.

My other motivation for doing so is that I  would like to be able to add some of these maven repositories *conditionally* based on some input property provided to gradle e.g.

```
gradle -Puse_repo=true <task>.
```

I thought if I was able to create my own entry, that I can add the check inside that entry to whether include the repository or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you can really add a new entry like `jcenter()` as those entries are essentially just methods on the built-in interface [`RepositoryHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html).

However, if you’re just trying to move your own repository configurations into a separate method/closure, then you can go with one of the following options:

```
def myNewRepos = {
    maven {
        url = "some url"
        name = "some name"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('use_repo')
          && project.property('use_repo') == 'true') {
        maven {
            url = "some other url"
            name = "some other name"
        }
    }
    // ... any others ...
}

/* OPTION 1: */
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    // ... any others ...
}
repositories myNewRepos

/* OPTION 2: */
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    // ... any others ...

    myNewRepos.delegate = owner
    myNewRepos()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This looks like it will work. Is there a way to make this conditional ? So only add this if a property is specified on the command line.

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed that part in your question. I have edited my answer to show how you can conditionally add a repository (named `some other name` in my sample code).

Comment: Oh perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I configured my company Nexus Maven repo:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://nexus.my-company.com/repository/maven-repo/"
        credentials {
            username "user"
            password "pass"
        }
    }
```

}